# All Frames with different Uris navigated to first created Frame

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, navigation

I create multiple `Frame` programmatically and navigate each `Frame` to different page, But all of `Frames` navigate to the `Uri` of first created `Frame` while the `Uri` is different.

**EDIT :** 
In my project user can open some items from his inbox list and view each item's page in different tab(each tab include a Frame).

If this is not possible, is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/201018/469184.aspx#469184

Comment: At least somebody understood the problem :) Well done. Glad you got an answer. +1 for posting it here too.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean the use of a hidden iframe to fool the browser into remembering URLs? 
If so, you cannot have multiple Uris in a single browser page. That is a browser limitation (where would it store multiple Uris anyway?).

If you are actually trying to have multiple navigable Silverlight applications in one Browser page can you please explain the problem you are trying to solve (as that is an unusual thing to do)?

If you mean something else, please clarify your question (and provide Xaml/html etc) and I will change my answer accordingly :)

Comment: Edit Post for more description.

Comment: @Navid Farhadi: Ok, just to clarify. You have the same Silverlight application running in multiple browser tabs. Can you provide sample  URLs for 2 different tabs as it is not clear what is going wrong? Thanks